# Insufficient fund for sending USDT token on an address with no Ether

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, tokens, tether, usdt

I've an [Ethereum account](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5bb2adf42182534fdb15bf1469cdc27c99cf6315#tokentxns) in Geth which has received 4 Tether (USDT). I want to send 1 of them for test to another account, but I receive this error:

> insufficient funds for gas * price + value

I think this is because there is not any deposited Ether in the source account. If I am right, how can I solve this issue?
My customers on this platform should be able to receive and send Tether, and I can not enforce them to have a deposit of Ether too.

Answer (score 1):

That error is saying that your account does not have enough ETH to pay the transaction fee. At this time, all transactions on Ethereum incur a fee paid for in ETH.

There are, however, ways too offload the fee payment to someone else with meta-transactions. Wallets like [Autheruem](https://authereum.com/) actually pay the transaction fees for you, so your users would not have to have any ETH.

*Disclaimer: I am a co-founder of Authereum.*